# How to create SQL procedure to select dynamic column from dynamic table where dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to create procedure to select dynamic column from dynamic data where dynamic value

```
Craete procedure SelectColumn
@tableName NVARCHAR(MAX),
@id int,
@ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX)

as
begin
DECLARE @SQLString1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLString1= 'Select '+ @ColumnName + ' From ' + @TableName +' where id= '+@id
    print @SQLString1
    EXEC (@SQLString1)
end
```

When execute show this error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Select Email
>   From Member where id= ' to data type int.

`when delete where id= '+@id  and set 'where id=1'` the procedure success, but I need use `where id=@id`.

Comment: SQL Injection possible.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code is far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @jarlh explain please

Comment: Tell us which database product you're using!

Comment: @lad2025 when edit where id=@id to where id=1 the query is success

Comment: @jarlh sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `CAST(@id AS VARCHAR)`

```
SET @SQLString1= 'Select '+ @ColumnName + ' From ' + @TableName +' where id= '+CAST(@id AS VARCHAR)
```